# Regex make labeled hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to make a labeled hyperlink from "[something](link)".

How can I convert the string to something like this: [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), the way it is done in forums?

Here is what I have tried, but I don't know regex very well:

```js
$(function() {

  var editor = $('.editor');

  $('.output').html(
    // editor.html().replace(/\[(.*)\)/g, '<a href="'+$1.replace(/\((.*)\)/g)+'">$1</a>')
    editor.html().replace(/\[(.*)\)/g, '<a href="">$1</a>')
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable class="editor">
  [something](link)
</div>
<div class="output">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/\[(.+)\]\((.+)\)/g` and then use `$1` to get the link's text and `$2` to get the link's `href` attribute :

> `$n` where `n` is the capturing group position in the regular expression (a number) : the first capturing group is `$1`, the second is `$2` and so on.

```js
$(() => {
  const editor = $('.editor');
  $('.output').html(editor.html().replace(/\[([^\[]+)\]\((.+)\)/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable class="editor">
  [a link](https://example.com)
</div>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: So the `$` things represent which "in between these characters" ?

Comment: @Souleste answer edited : *$n where n is the capturing group position in the regular expression...*.

Comment: I have a question about this, say I have this: [something] [something](link), the first capture group captures everything between the very first bracket and the very last bracket. how would I fix that?

Comment: @Souleste see updated answer, used `/\[([^\[]+)\]\((.+)\)/` so `[something] [something](link)` produces `[something] <a href="link">something</a>` (the first [something] is ignored as it doesn't respect the pattern).

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

This regex should do what you want.

`/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g`

This regex also takes care about input strings like `[something] [something](link)`.

`\[([^\[]*?)\]\((.*?)\)`

## Explanation

This regex matches everything within square brackets into capture group 1 directly followed by a curved brackets pair which contents go into capture group 2. Capture groups are defined by a curved bracket pair. Afterwards those capture groups can be accessed by using $1 and $2.

The regex also covering the input string `[something] [something](link)` does not match everything within a bracket pair but instead matches everything except opening brackets.

## Example

Here is the updated snippet which you posted.

```js
$(function() {

  var editor = $('.editor');

  $('.output').html(
    editor.html().replace(/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>')
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable class="editor">
  [something](link)
</div>
<div class="output">

</div>
```

Comment: I didn't realize that you could put multiple searches inside of a replace. Can you explain to me how the `$` work with regex?

Comment: I have a question about this, say I have this: `[something] [something](link)`, the first capture group captures everything between the very first bracket and the very last bracket. how would I fix that?